# How to balance this half-equations

Tags: redox

HNO$_3 \rightarrow $ N$_2$O(g)

I'm looking at the solution and it says that the above reaction can be modified as

NO$_3^-$(aq) $\rightarrow$ N$_2$O (g)

I don't understand why. Can someone please explain?

I understand the steps afterwards but I don't understand this initial step.

Comment: Have you heard about strong acids?

Comment: yes. so because hno3 is a strong acid, that's why?

Comment: You do not really need to answer that, do you?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it's because nitric acid is a strong acid. At concentrations where we generally perform aqueous chemistry, it is essentially completely dissociated to give $\ce{H^+(aq)}$ and $\ce{NO3^-}$. So the nitrogen-bearing species that does the oxidizing is primarily the dissociated ion $\ce{NO3^-}$. As you balance the reaction you will also see the $\ce{H^+(aq)}$ as part of the balancing process for charge and hydrogen.

You may want to compare this methodology with that described in [this case](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/144538/17175), where the acid is only a weak one (hypochlorous acid). You therefore have to design your half-reactions to simultaneously balance protons and electrons so that the acid does not have to dissociate strongly.